# How can I define two global `const` variables to the same value in a C module?

Tags: c, constants, global-variables, extern

I’m using a pair of global variables in one of my `.c` files, matched to a single `extern` declaration each in two different `.h` files (well, one `.h` file, preprocessed two ways). One is for public consumption, and one is for private use. Both are `const` variables.

I only want to initialize one of the variables in my `.c` file, and then assign the second variable to the same content. Here’s the relevant contents of the `.c` file at the moment:

```
struct List_methods const List = {
  .create         = List__create,
  .create_naughty = List__create_naughty,
  // …
};
struct List_methods const Paws__List = List;
```

… and the corresponding .h:

```
#if defined(EXTERNALIZE)
# define  List_methods  Paws__List_methods
# define  List          Paws__List
#endif

// …

struct List_methods {
  list  (*create)         (void);
  list  (*create_naughty) (void);
  // …
} const extern List;

#if defined(EXTERNALIZE)
# undef   List_methods  Paws__List_methods
# undef   List          Paws__List
#endif
```

The goal here, is to ensure that when the `.h` is included with `EXTERNALIZE` defined, the including file gains access to the `Paws__List` variable, `extern`’d to the definition in my `.c` file. However, if it’s included *without* that definition, they gain access to an `extern`’d `List` instead (which I intend to use in my internal files, and make available if the `#include`er wants it).

However, the `Paws__List = List` assignment blows up in my compiler, with the following error:

```
Source/Paws.o/list/list.c:32:40: error: initializer element is not a
      compile-time constant
struct List_methods const Paws__List = List;
                                       ^~~~
```

I’m looking for any help I can get to make this work as described above (that is, to define two `const` names for the same struct in my `.c` file, such that one or the other can be referenced by the `.h` header.)

Comment: Paws__List is intended to be a _copy_ of List? not a reference or some sort of alias?

Comment: It’s intended to reference the same thing. It’s not supposed to be a pointer, though. i.e. code that uses `extern Paws__List` should get the *same thing* as code that uses `extern List`, as long as both compile against this `.c` file.

Comment: Are there cases where both should not be the same?

Comment: "I only want to initialize one of the variables in my .c file, and then assign the second variable to the same content". If it helps, the thing that blows up in the compiler *is* an initialization, not an assignment. I don't think I quite understand the question, what's preventing you from just doing `#define Paws__List (List)` everywhere that uses the Paws version, and the same for the type name? And why are you using a reserved name? ;-)

Comment: The define isn’t good enough; I want to actually have two different interfaces to the same thing… and what reserved name am I using?

Comment: @elliottcable, double underscores are reserved for the compiler, an C++ compiler for example might use them for name-mangling

Comment: Ah, just the double-underscores thing. AFAIK that’s only C++; I never intend to build this codebase with a C++ compiler (why would I?), so it doesn’t matter. Thanks, though—+1 for the information (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want to define an interface (vtable) and the implementation will vary depending on EXTERNALIZE:

I'd go that route:

```
/* header file */
/* define the interface */
typedef struct List_methods {
  list  (*create)         (void);
  list  (*create_naughty) (void);
  // …
} List_Methods;

const extern List_methods Paws_List; // note: double underscores are afaik not allowed
const extern List_methods Other_List; // take any name but List

#ifdef EXTERNALIZE
# define  List          Paws_List
#else
# define  List          Other_List
#end
```

The important thing is that the structures are of the same type else you cannot assign one to the
other. Second I would't override a symbol with an alias. This only makes problems when you want to use both for example in your .c file.

Comment: No, that’s backwards: I only want to expose *one* interface, but it’s a different interface depending on `EXTERNALIZE`.

Specifically, most people building against my library will include `Paws.h`, which sets `EXTERNALIZE` and then includes the other headers from my library. That file sets up a struct that *contains* these other structs, like `Paws.List.…`. That means that `List` itself isn’t available under that name; instead, it is provided as `Paws__List`, which is then stored under the `Paws` struct.

Comment: However, *inside* my library, (and optionally, if people include my headers directly (individually) without going through the global `Paws.h`), when `.c` files are compiled alone, `List` is defined itself, as are all of my other namespaces; it’s the opposite of the above. This allows me to maintain two APIs: an internal API that consists of a bunch of `const` variables (`List`, `Numeric`, `String`, etc)… and an external one, where *everything* is safely stored under `Paws` (to avoid conflicts when people build against it.)

Comment: So, all that explained… the `List.h` file, the one described in the question, needs to either `extern` a `List` definition (when included into internal files), or `extern` a `Paws__List` definition (when included into `Paws.h`, which sets `EXTERNALIZE`… and then stores `Paws__List` and friends on an `extern`’d `Paws` variable).